# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 34 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter

I am getting Error when try to run below script. I am using Expanded widget for showing user followers.

```
Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              buildCountColumn("posts", postCount),
                              buildCountColumn("followers", followerCount),
                              buildCountColumn("following", followingCount),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              buildProfileButton(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Expanded parentWidget and get an `Expanded` Widget for every Widget

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

## your **buildProfileButton() or row ** is creating more size widgets then the space available in screen;

Two solutions:

1. you can put your row in listview to make it scrollable
2. #### put each one in Expanded like:

   Expanded(
   child:buildCountColumn("posts", postCount),
   )
   **to take limited available size in screen -> divided equally within all childs**
   :: always use expanded/listview/scrollable/widget size less than total screen width
   you can get it by **mediaQuery.of(context).size.width** for flexible row